# Protobuf-net and WebApi, which format to use to return data over the wire?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, protobuf-net

I have a .Net Core 3.1 WebAPI that:

1. Serialize my obj with: ProtoBuf.Serializer.Serialize(stream,
   myobject);
2. Return it with: Convert.ToBase64String(stream.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)stream.Length);

and a Blazor WASM app that call the WebAPI and

1. Get the data from the wire: MemoryStream stream = new
   MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(await
   response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()));
2. and then deserialize it back to my obj: myobj = ProtoBuf.Serializer.Deserialize(stream);

Everything works fine but my doubt is this can be optimized and avoid some conversion to byte[] / base4 string and back.

Is this the correct way to transfer protobuf data over the wire or can this be done in a better way?

Comment: Interesting question. I genuinely don't know the answer, but here's hoping...

Comment: You can send binary data (byte[]) over http - no base64 encoding, i never had trouble doing that. Less bytes over wire and no string conversion (base64) back and forth.

Comment: @FrankNielsen could you share some code both API and Client side?

Answer (score 0):

How to send raw bytes over the http wire:

```
var binaryContent = new ByteArrayContent(new byte[] { 1, 2, 3 });
binaryContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
content.Add(binaryContent, "content");

var result = await client.PostAsync("api/bytes/incoming", content);
```

The trick is that the receiver must be aware of "ContentType: application/octet-stream" which is not default for most web servers. So the server side requires a little more effort:

```
public class RawRequestBodyFormatter : InputFormatter
{
    public RawRequestBodyFormatter()
    {
        SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/plain"));
        SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream"));
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Allow text/plain, application/octet-stream and no content type to
    /// be processed
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public override Boolean CanRead(InputFormatterContext context)
    {
        if (context == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));

        var contentType = context.HttpContext.Request.ContentType;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(contentType) || contentType == "text/plain" ||
            contentType == "application/octet-stream")
            return true;

        return false;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Handle text/plain or no content type for string results
    /// Handle application/octet-stream for byte[] results
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public override async Task<InputFormatterResult> ReadRequestBodyAsync(InputFormatterContext context)
    {
        var request = context.HttpContext.Request;
        var contentType = context.HttpContext.Request.ContentType;


        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(contentType) || contentType == "text/plain")
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(request.Body))
            {
                var content = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
                return await InputFormatterResult.SuccessAsync(content);
            }
        }
        if (contentType == "application/octet-stream")
        {
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream(2048))
            {
                await request.Body.CopyToAsync(ms);
                var content = ms.ToArray();
                return await InputFormatterResult.SuccessAsync(content);
            }
        }

        return await InputFormatterResult.FailureAsync();
    }
}
```

and at Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc(o => o.InputFormatters.Insert(0, new RawRequestBodyFormatter()));
}
```

and the controller

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/bytes/incoming")]
public byte[] RawBytesFormatter([FromBody] byte[] rawData)
{
    return rawData;
}
```

I took the server-side snippets from Rick Strahl excellent blog post about this: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2017/Sep/14/Accepting-Raw-Request-Body-Content-in-ASPNET-Core-API-Controllers?Page=2

- all kudos to him :)

Answer (score 0):

I found that the WebAPI can directly return the stream where ProtoBuf.Serializer.Serialize has written into. The point here is not dispose the stream (let it do to the GC).

The client can ProtoBuf.Serializer.Deserialize the response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().

**BUT**

**I stick with Base64string so that the content is gzipped by the server while a stream is not.**